# Angular Material: Why does mat-form does not wrap the mat-hint inside?

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I want my form fields to look right. However, the hint text of a first field intersects the second field below it and the text appears dirty. My goal is to separate these overlapping texts.But I haven't found a solution yet. How can I solve this problem?

I don't want the form to look like in the picture.

[image: problem image]

**Edit**: I'm using the method suggested on his Angular official site.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnkmogrbgry?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts

**Edit 2**:
**userform.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto mt-5">
  <mat-card class="fullbar">
    <div class="card-header-bar">
      New User Form!
    </div>
    <mat-card-content class="mt-3 card-content-bar">

      <form [formGroup]="userGroup">

        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
          <mat-hint>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nibh dui, viverra quis lacinia
            non, volutpat vel nisi. Donec fringilla, sem id vestibulum semper, diam ligula venenatis ligula, nec
            malesuada nisi mi at lectus.
          </mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
          <mat-hint>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nibh dui, viverra quis lacinia
            non, volutpat vel nisi. Donec fringilla, sem id vestibulum semper, diam ligula venenatis ligula, nec
            malesuada nisi mi at lectus.
          </mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>


        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Age" formControlName="age">
          <mat-hint>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nibh dui, viverra quis lacinia
            non, volutpat vel nisi. Donec fringilla, sem id vestibulum semper, diam ligula venenatis ligula, nec
            malesuada nisi mi at lectus.
          </mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

      </form>

    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

**userform.component.css**

```
.fullbar {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 225px;
}

.card-header-bar {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54);
  background-color: #e7e5f7;
}

.card-content-bar {
  padding: 15px;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You stackblitz does not contain `mat-hint` elements.

Comment: Pleas put an examle of your hint's in a stackblitz application.

Comment: @leopal and @ Mises i added my full codes. Just a lot of things same except `<mat-hint>` commands at `stackblitz.com`. Since I use standard commands, how can I solve this?

Comment: There is an open issue discussing this: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4580

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set height of mat-form-field to auto.

Comment: I tried this `style="height: auto"` but didn't worked.

Comment: What about other options like fit-content, it will be awsome if you can provide stackblitz that will present your problem.

Comment: Also what about setting it to !important ?

Comment: I also tried this `style="height: auto !important;"` but didn't work.

Comment: Also all my codes are shown in section `edit 2`. I don't have a different code.I don't know what fit-content is.

Comment: Okey here i created stackblitz with solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upvyzj i just added margin to .full-width. Thats not the best solution but i cant find other.

Comment: So the problem is that hint position is set to absolute and parent cant wrap around it. You can try changing its style relative ot else, but its not recommended to change material styles.

Comment: Thank you. The distance between the form fields is very long. It's not provide what I wants. Now, I am trying to use css `@media` object for different screen size but it was not work.  Do you know how to use about css `@media` object?

Comment: Link to @media : https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/ but im pretty sure you can also use grid : https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/